# Unable to Google Change Of Address from Old Site to New Site

Tags: wordpress, redirect, http-status-code-301, http-redirect, google-search-console

I have setup redirects from the old site to the new site but Google is giving an error when I try to do the change of address.

This is in my .htaccess

```
Redirect 301 https://www.thebackcountrytrail.com https://highaltitudebrands.com
Redirect 301 http://www.thebackcountrytrail.com https://highaltitudebrands.com
Redirect 301 http://thebackcountrytrail.com https://highaltitudebrands.com
Redirect 301 https://thebackcountrytrail.com https://highaltitudebrands.com
```

and this is the error I am getting:

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

Please add below code in your `.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^olddomain.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.olddomain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://newdomain.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

Or you could also use `301 redirect` plugin.

Comment: That code redirects all of the pages to the new site but the site paths are not all the exact same so I am using a plugin called Redirection to redirect specific pages to the new pages on the new site.

Comment: Using http://www.redirect-checker.org/index.php everything checks out fine

Result
CONGRATULATION. Everything seems to be fine.

http://thebackcountrytrail.com/
301 Moved Permanently
https://www.thebackcountrytrail.com/
301 Moved Permanently
https://highaltitudebrands.com
200 OK

Comment: That Raju but this was not the solution I needed as it redirected all of my pages and I ONLY wanted the homepage.

Answer (score -1):

By adding this code to my .htaccess file I was able to redirect ONLY the homepage which is what Google was looking for.  I am using Redirection plugin in wordpress to redirect all other pages to the new pages on the new site.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^$ https://highaltitudebrands.com/ [R=301,L]
```